# How to refresh a webView? (All that I get are FC's!)

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I'm wanting to refresh my web view when I press on a menu button. This is my code:

**TuzzaMobileActivity.java**

```
package com.wiseheart.TuzzaMobile;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class TuzzaMobileActivity extends Activity {
    final Activity activity = this;
    private WebView webView; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                // Handle the error
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://johnwiseheart.me");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.quit:
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.refresh:
            webView.loadUrl( "http://johnwiseheart.me" );
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I have the buttons set up properly in that the exit button works, but whenever I click on my refresh button, I get an FC! What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 7):

You have defined a field

```
private WebView webView;
```

in your class, but you then assign to a local variable instead:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

The solution is to change that line to

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late, but this is what i use inside my onOptionsSelected.

```
case R.id.reload_title: //If the ID equals 3 , go refresh
   item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_refresh);
   web.reload();
     return true;
```

In this case my Webview is called web.

I have updated your above source code

Comment: @ I dont know if you were able to get this resolve, but from what i can see all you are doing when refreshing is reload the default page, if you want the refresh button to refresh the actual page the end user is on, instead of just taking them back to the home page then use this code snippet in your menu item   `case R.id.reload_title: //If the ID equals 3 , go refresh
   item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_refresh);
   webView.reload();
     return true;`